# GitHub: problem pushing a local branch to the remote

Tags: git, github

I created a local branch but now I'm struggling to push it to the server.

After coding I did:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

When I use the command:

```
git push -u origin name/feature
```

I have the following error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://myUserName:myToken@github.com/githuburl/' not found
```

First I thought the problem was with my new generated token but I tested it cloning the repo in a test folder - it worked.

What am I missing?

UPD. The branch name contains a slash - so it looks like "name/feature".

Solution found. It turned out I had only permission to read, but not to write.

I

Comment: @matt can you please elaborate on it? I'm not sure what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @matt No, it doesn't. My problem is the admin forgot to grant me the right for writing.

Answer (score 1):

The repo URI you are trying to push to doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to access it (GitHub pretends that private repos you don't have access to don't exist). Run

```sh
git remote get-url origin
```

and make sure what you see is *exactly* what GitHub shows you after clicking the green Code button:

[image: Screenshot of GitHub UI displaying a clone URI]

Comment: Thanks but I do not understand how it may help. I run this command and it shows me my repo url. what's next?

Comment: @mimic Is it the same as the URI GitHub shows you in that dialog?

Comment: As I described in the question, I checked both: repo url and my credentials - both worked.

Comment: Yes, I compared them, they are identical.

Comment: @mimic Perhaps you have your authentication settings different within the repo, which is causing GitHub to reject your pushes. Does `git config --list` give the same output in the repo you are trying to push from as the repo you created in a test directory?

Comment: It shows a lot of things (not sure what they are) and remote.origin.url= exactly url I'm using for pushing

Comment: @mimic Are the config options starting with `credential` the same?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I have the section on config titled "[remote "origin"]" and it has url and this url is the same, yes. It already contains my username and token access - I used the same url to clone and I succeeded. I also was able to switch to another branch.

Comment: I also was able to pull from another branch. But I can't push!